# Using a R function in python notebook to visualize missing data

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2, rpy2

[naniar](https://github.com/njtierney/naniar) is a common R package for visualizing missing data. I am trying to use `rpy2` to call an R function `vis_miss()` in `naniar` to plot the missing data.

Python is giving me a data frame as output instead of a plot in my notebook and I would like to solve this. The idea is to use the `vis_miss` package in a python notebook.

Below is a working example using `iris` dataset:

```
# install rpy2 to run R in python
!pip3 install rpy2

%load_ext rpy2.ipython


from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

%R install.packages("naniar")
%R library(naniar)
%R library(ggplot2)


# Load Iris data
iris = load_iris()


# Run vis_miss function, expecting to see a graph showing missing data
%R naniar::vis_miss(iris)
```

My output should now be an image of missing data but instead I get:

```
ListVector with 10 elements.
data    R/rpy2 DataFrame (750 x 4)
rows    variable    valueType   value
... ... ... ...
layers  ListVector with 1 elements.
[no name]   [RTYPES.ENVSXP]
scales  add: function clone: function find: function get_scales: function has_scale: function input: function n: function non_position_scales: function scales: list super:
... ...
plot_env    
labels  ListVector with 4 elements.
x   [RTYPES.STRSXP]
y   [RTYPES.STRSXP]
text    [RTYPES.STRSXP]
fill    [RTYPES.STRSXP]
guides  ListVector with 1 elements.
fill    [RTYPES.VECSXP]
```

How can I get the required output that would occur in R, within a cell in this python notebook?

Would I perhaps use `matplotlib` or `ggplot2` here?

Comment: This may be due to interactivity of R plots in Python kernel of Jupyter notebook (same with `rpy2` in Python script). Instead of actual plot you get the underlying ggplot data dump. Consider saving the plot to an image file and render it in a subsequent cell. Or run an R kernel.

Comment: Hi @Parfait, how can I save is as an image in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cell magic (`%%R`) to get the output as an image:

```
%%R
naniar::vis_miss(iris)
```

The cell magic also allows to customize width/height/dpi and format, see: [IPython magic integration](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/interactive.html).

[image: its working]

Comment: This is so beautiful I just shed a tear with Hans Zimmer playing in the background :D ...  On a serious note. Thank you for the help @krassowski .